# Changing from fiscal to calendar year

Tags: tableau-api

I am working on a dashboard where the user wants to change dates from a fiscal year to a calendar year from January 2017 going forward while keeping all data and continuing to display data prior to the change date in fiscal year format.

I have looked at using a calculated field with dateadd clocking the date back  a month but it skews the data when the gap between fiscal and calendar month is rolled into 2017.

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Comment: This is an interesting requirement. Switching between calendar and fiscal year will surely result in inaccurate annual totals for the year the switch occurred. Can you post your calculated field code?

Comment: Question here is what is your requirement that is going wrong when you switch between both,

Comment: The US govt changed its fiscal year in 1976 and tracked it by introducing a transitional quarter for reporting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiscal_year#Federal_government. Decide  how you want to report the transitional period, make it clear to everyone and reach agreement, then the calculated fields should be easy in comparison. What was the FY boundary month in the past?